# Mercurial 2.7.2 & TortoiseHg error running HG

Tags: python, mercurial, tortoisehg, traceback

I just installed the Mercurial 2.7.2 and combined TortoiseHg package from https://www.mercurial-scm.org/.

Am I supposed to be able to access Mercurial from a Windows console? When I open a console and simply type hg, I get the following instead of a list of commands:

**Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.**

**C:\Users\Darren>hg**

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\py2exe\boot_common.py", line 92, in 
ImportError: No module named linecache
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named zipextimporter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hg", line 10, in 
ImportError: No module named os**

Shouldn't the installer from https://www.mercurial-scm.org have everything needed for this to work?

I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 and I'm logged on with admin privilege account.

Answer (score 0):

> I just installed the Mercurial 2.7.2 and combined TortoiseHg package

Too much. TortoiseHG already have Mercurial's CLI interface. And TortoiseHG interfere with existing Python, which is bad - TortoiseHG contains **all** needed inside ...\TortoiseHg\library.zip